# jQuery to submit form to new tab?

Tags: jquery

I have an action link in a form that needs to be updated with a token every minute. I get the new url/token from an api call when the user clicks on the submit button. I'm using something like this

```
 <form id="somelink" action="http://some.external.url/" target="_blank" />

 $('#somebutton').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = '/apicall?id=' + $('#someid').val();                  
      $.post(url, function(data) {
           $('#somelink').attr('action', data);
           $('#somelink').submit();
```

problem is, using js/jQuery when it submits it opens in a new window without the typical menu and buttons in the browser and it's the size of a popup window.

Without the jQuery if I just clicked on the button it'll open in a new tab.

How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

Comment: You can catch the submit event, instead of catching the click event and let the event carry through.. In case of any error, use e.preventDefault()..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of catching the `click` event, try catching the `submit` event of the form and in case you find any error you can use event.preventDefault();
**Update**
Here i tested with this code and it's working fine,

```
<!doctype html />
<html>
  <head>        
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action='http://someSite.com' id='somelink' target='_blank'>
    <input type='text' name='lol' id='lol'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript"/>
      $('#somelink').on('submit',function(e) {
          if($('#lol').val() == "poop"){ //Sample error check
              e.preventDefault();
              alert($('#lol').val());
          }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What this does is, if you enter "poop" it does not submit the form, for anything else it submits the form to new tab. Hope this helps :) 
**Update:** 
Regarding your comment, if in case of error you want to open some other tab, then replace `e.preventDefault()` with `$(this).attr({"action":"http://www.someothersite.com"});` . Hope this helps :)
**Update:**
If you want to open a tab asynchronously, then you would have a hard time, this is the closest it can get. 
HTML Part

```
<form id="someForm" action="about:blank" target="newStuff" />
<input type="submit" value="12345" id="someid" />
```

Javascript Part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#someForm').submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != "") {     
                var link = "http://www.google.com/";
                window.open(link,'newStuff'); //open's link in newly opened tab!
            }
        }
    });
 });
 });
```

Comment: thanks, I know how preventDefault works though, I was looking for a solution to preventDefault the click or submit and then redirect to a new tab vs window

Comment: I've update the fiddle, Also i updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: actually this code the first submit creates the tab and then the ajax code opens the new link within that tab, customer would see two refreshes in that tab. any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: That's the hard part, now the thing is we can redirect the tab or close the tab from our own page but the fact is the tab will be made. Preferably in about:blank; To close the tab we need to do the following-> a=window.open(link,'newStuff'); and also a.close(); to close it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

I had this same issue, here's how I solved it:

```
<form action="..." method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" id="btn-form-submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    $('#btn-submit').click( function(){ $('#btn-form-submit').click(); } );
</script>
```

This submits the form into a new tab (_blank) without using the native submit button.

Answer (score 10):

```
jQuery("#availability_players_form").attr("target","_blank");

jQuery("#availability_players_form").submit();
```

Where `#availability_players_form = form id`

Answer (score 2):

You already defined the target as `"_blank"` so try the code below and see the example link than you will see how it works.. and try `$.post` without submitting or you can use `ajax` to keep data somewhere in the background and send it to the new tab..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#YourForm').submit(function() { // <---- Your form submit event
        $(this).target = "_blank"; // <---- to new tab
        $.post(url, function(data) {
            // whatever you wanna post do it here
        });
        window.open($(this).prop('action')); // <---- form action attribute = url
        return false; // <---- prevents submit
   });
});​
```

or using ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#YourForm').submit(function() { // <---- Your form submit event
        $(this).target = "_blank";  // <---- to new tab
        var json = $.toJSON({ yourjsondata1: data1, yourjsondata2: data2 });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/some/url",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                window.open($(this).prop('action')); // <---- form action attribute = url
            }
        });
        return false; // <---- prevents submit
   });
});​
```

See this example :

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/open-link-in-new-tab-or-new-popup.html

**Edit:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#someid').click(function() {
         // lets say you got ur data from your post method
         var url = '/api?id=' + $('#someid').val(); 
         $.post(url, function(data) {
             if (data != '') {
                 // update your link
                 $('#somelink').attr('action', data);
                 // update target to new tab
                 $("#somelink").target = '_blank';
                 // than go
                 window.open($("#somelink").attr('action'));
                 return false;
             } else {
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/nfTWL/

Comment: this is a good start, it works for absolute a href links, how would I incorporate this concept into a form submission?

Comment: @archytect are you supposed to return some data after submission? if so using `getJSON` or `ajax GET` methods would be wise and do you really need to submit form before redirecting to a new tab? also if you can show a little example of your code in jsfiddle i can improve my answer for your needs further more.

Comment: I'm taken apart the form and changed it to a simple button.

the code looks more like this now

http://jsfiddle.net/mAkV8/

it's still opening in a new window instead of a tab whereas the example from that link if I were to copy and patse it would go to a new tab

Comment: I need to get a new url/token as each link expires every minute so when they click on the button I need to retrieve a new link, append that to the href and open that href in a new tab

Comment: yours work fine, it's just when you actually use it in a post/ajax block it opens in a popup. Here's a modified version of your code

http://jsfiddle.net/nfTWL/1/

Comment: here's a jsfiddle of your submit code, it opens in a new popup as well

http://jsfiddle.net/nfTWL/12/

Comment: Ok i tried it couple times and it works on Maxthon - Opera - Safari - Firefox but doesnt work on IE - Chrome.. so i ll try to make it crossbrowser..

Answer (score 1):

you can use `target="_newtab"`

```
<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, form submits to the same window unless the form is inside a modal/modeless window dialog .If your form is indeed inside modal/modeless dialog, you need to set the window name with whatever the form target is.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.name = "posthereonly";
</script>
</head>
```

and change the form target to

```
  <form id="somelink" action="http://some.external.url/" target="posthereonly" />
```

see if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this would work for you, no need for Jake Weary - just vanilla JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms['order_filter'].target='_blank';document.forms['order_filter'].submit();">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"` to your form.

**Edit:** To submit `<form>` to new tab/window, you don't even need JS/jQuery.

Comment: The OP did this already and obviously it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @ascripter my answer answers the title question (to submit form to new tab/window by JS, you don't even need JS/jQuery, just target=_blank is enough). What the OP is asking for (open a new/window by JS/jQuery) is not allowed to be accomplished by browsers (link has to be clicked organically by user). To open it by JS, will have to write a JS script to create new window popup (which is a bit different than opening new tab/window) [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: thanks for your comment, if I understand you right you're arguing that the question actually suggests bad practice or even a misunderstanding by the OP. Maybe you can elaborate that in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine with me. I have tried this. It may help you. Make some changes as per your requirement and it will work.

```
<form action="..." method="GET" target="_blank">
   <input type="submit" id-"btn-form-submit"/>
</form>
<script>
   $('#btn-submit').click( function(){ $('#btn-form-submit').click(); } );
</script>
```

Comment: You literally copied my answer from two months prior, including the "id-" mistake I made.