# jquery + ajax - redirect after submit form in new tab with no button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to submit my form **in new tab** and after the submit redirect to another page. (response not required)

HTML

```
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

</head>


<form  action="my url" name="myForm" id="myForm"  target="_blank">
-------
------
</form>
```

jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(function() {
      $.ajax({  
          type: $('#myForm').attr('method'),  
          url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),  
          data: $('#myForm').serialize(),       
          success: function(){  
              alert("success"); 
          //redirect to another page
          }  
      });
    });


</script>
```

I don't have any buttons. There are many examples, but none of them works for me.

**UPDATE:** The problem is that my form doesn't submit. The form url I am using to submit the data, "my url" is a payment page url.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527436/jquery-to-submit-form-to-new-tab

Comment: how you want to submit the form , I mean what will make your form submit ie will call the ajax ?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  Is the AJAX call not happening?  Is it failing in some way?  If there doesn't need to be a response, what does it need to be in a new tab?

Comment: please see my update, my form does not submitted.

Comment: try assigning a jquery function to a forms onSubmit. Don't forget the preventDefault!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$.ajax({  
  type: $('#myForm').attr('method'),  
  url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),  
  data: $('#myForm').serialize(),       
  success: function(){  
      alert("success"); 
  //redirect to another page
window.open(
'www.google.com',
'_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new tab.
);
}  
});
});
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, please see my update, the problem is that form doesn't submitted, so success function does not called

Answer (score 0):

If success doesn't work for you, try with `error`

```
$.ajax({  
  type: $('#myForm').attr('method'),  
  url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),  
  data: $('#myForm').serialize(),       
  success: function(){  
      alert("success"); 
  }
  error: function(e){
      console.log(e);
  }
});
```